# How do you create a shortcut to a folder in Windows Installer?

Tags: windows-installer, directory, shortcut, wise

I need to install a shortcut that opens one of the folders that I'm creating. What mist I do to create a shortcut whose target is a folder instead of a file? I tried making the folder the shortcut's target, but when I try to install the application, Windows Installer tells me that the shortcut can't be created even though both the destination folder (the target folder's parent) and the target folder itself exist by the end of the install.

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that I'm using Wise Windows Installer Editor.

Still waiting for an answer that I can use. Even if it's what to put in the Shortcuts table itself. (Cichy's answer doesn't help me, because it's obviously geared to a specific IDE (which he doesn't mention), and from the instructions given, it's obviously not Wise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a response in one of the Microsoft forums that I was able to use. It goes as follows:

> In the ‘Shortcut’ table, give the directory path to ‘target’ filed. You may
>   need Orca or something like IS direct editor to do that.
>   Example
>   Target - > [INSTALLDIR]Documents\ShortCutDir

In my case, I simply put the key name of my folder (from the Directory table) in square brackets.
Example
Target - > [MyTargetDir]

Answer (score 0):

in the "File System (setup project)" window, click right mouse button on directory you want to create shortcut (lets say "Application Folder" inside "File System on target machine".
Choose "Create Shortcut to Application folder".
Shortcut will be created in this directory, and than you simply drag&drop it on "User's Programs Menu" or where ever you want it to have.